# HTML form submit popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a HTML form on my site. When I fill it and click submit my action endpoint works fine. I want to do the following with it. When submit is clicked:

1. Post the form data to the action endpoint
2. Overlay a Thank you message with a button or maybe just a message that disappears after a couple of seconds
3. Once the overlay disappears I want the form cleared but the user to return back to the same page.

My basic form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://mywebsite.com/formdata">
<div class="fields">
    <div class="field half">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="field half">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="actions">
    <li><input type="submit" value="Send" class="primary" /></li>
</ul>
```

I tried modifying the code by adding overlay code from some online guides I found as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="https://mywebsite.com/formdata">
<div class="fields">
    <div class="field half">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="field half">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="actions">
    <li><input class="trigger_popup_fricc" type="submit" value="Send" class="primary" /></li>
</ul>
<div class="hover_bkgr_fricc">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <div>
        <div class="popupCloseButton">X</div>
        <p>Add any HTML content<br />inside the popup box!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added the class added on the submit button and the hover popup div below it. Then the CSS added was:

```
    /* Popup box BEGIN */
.hover_bkgr_fricc{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10000;
}
.hover_bkgr_fricc .helper{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.hover_bkgr_fricc > div {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px #555;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 551px;
    min-height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 15px 5%;
}
.popupCloseButton {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #999;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.popupCloseButton:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.trigger_popup_fricc {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
/* Popup box BEGIN */
```

And the javascript added was:

```
    $(window).load(function () {
    $(".trigger_popup_fricc").click(function(){
       $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').show();
    });
    $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').click(function(){
        $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').hide();
    });
    $('.popupCloseButton').click(function(){
        $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').hide();
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work. There is no popup. Any guidance on how to achieve the tasks I want to do would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you submit a form, you're actually leaving the page. The current page stops executing, unless you submit via XHR using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add an ajax request to the url enpoint and fetch the response. But as mentioned in another answer you need to use `preventDefault()` to avoid refresh when clicking send button.

Here's a jsfiddle for the same - https://jsfiddle.net/ekLys4qa/1/

```js
$(".trigger_popup_fricc").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var my_inputs = {
    name: $("#name").val(),
    email: $("#email").val(),
    message: $("#message").val()
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://httpbin.org/post", // change it to your application specific url
    data: my_inputs,
    success: function(data, status){
     console.log(data);
      console.log(status);
      $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').show();
    },
    error: function(err){
     console.log(err);
    }
  });
  // for resetting the form
  $("#name").val("");
  $("#email").val("");
  $("#message").val("");
});

$('.popupCloseButton').click(function(){
  $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').hide();
});
```

```css
   /* Popup box BEGIN */
.hover_bkgr_fricc{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10000;
}
.hover_bkgr_fricc .helper{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.hover_bkgr_fricc > div {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px #555;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 551px;
    min-height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 15px 5%;
}
.popupCloseButton {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #999;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.popupCloseButton:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.trigger_popup_fricc {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
/* Popup box BEGIN */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<div class="fields">
    <div class="field half">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="field half">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="actions">
<li><button class="trigger_popup_fricc primary" id="btn" type="submit" value="Send">Send</button></li>
</ul>
</form>
<div class="hover_bkgr_fricc">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <div>
        <div class="popupCloseButton">X</div>
        <p>Add any HTML content<br />inside the popup box!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reponse. I was able to get it to work with your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you trigger the click event after sending the form and leaving the page. If you want to stay on that page I would suggest using AJAX to send the form and process response.

Here you can find the hint for AJAX using `.post()`. First of all I call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent all the default behaviour of the clicked button. Then I read all the form data and put it as input of AJAX call.

If the AJAX is successful I show the popup, if not it jumps into `.fail()`.

This is just a hint. You still need to write server side script to process form data and return response and write success and fail cases in JS.

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    $(".trigger_popup_fricc").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var inputData = {
            name: $("#name").val(),
            email: $("email").val(),
            message: $("#message").val()
        }
        $.post('https://mywebsite.com/formdata', inputData, function(data){
            // Process the response with data returned from the script
            $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').show();
        })
        .fail(function() {
            // Process if error
        });
    });
    $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').click(function(){
        $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').hide();
    });
    $('.popupCloseButton').click(function(){
        $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').hide();
    });
});
```

I have also slightly modified you HTML.

```
<form>
<div class="fields">
    <div class="field half">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="field half">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="actions">
    <li><input class="trigger_popup_fricc primary" type="submit" value="Send" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
<div class="hover_bkgr_fricc">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <div>
        <div class="popupCloseButton">X</div>
        <p>Add any HTML content<br />inside the popup box!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I was able to get it to work with your help.